# Unparsable date exception MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss a z

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
     String inputStr = "05/01/2012 10:51:47 AM PDT";
     String inputFmt = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
     SimpleDateFormat dfLong = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFmt);;
     Date localModifiedDate = dfLong.parse(inputStr);
     System.out.println(localModifiedDate);
```

Gives me Unparsable date exception

Answer (score 2):

Your default `Locale` may be not be capable of to parsing the `AM/PM` marker and/or timezone. Try the `ENGLISH` `Locale`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dfLong = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFmt, Locale.ENGLISH);
```